# The trace of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading a matrix algebra textbook.

It introduces an equation $(x-a)^TA(x-a)=tr(Ax_cx_c^T)+n(a-\bar{x})^2tr(A)$ where $ x_c = x - \bar{x}$.

Is this equation really right? I failed to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: One way of doing this is to actually calculate the left-hand side and the right-hand side in the $2\times2$ case, either with general matrices (letters and such), or with whatever numbers you like. See if you can spot some underlying reason why it should be true.

Comment: Is this supposed to be true for arbitrary $A$?  Also, does $(a - \bar x)^2$ mean $\|a - \bar x\|^2$?  And what is $n$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom According to the context in the textbook it is supposed to be true for arbitrary real symmetric matrix. n is the dimension of the vector space and A is a matrix of $n \times n$.

Comment: All right.  What about the rest of my question?  Do we know anything in particular about $x_c$ and $\bar x$?  Does $\bar x$ have a particular meaning here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom They are all real vectors in the same vector space. $\bar{x}$ is the vector with all entries having the same value, which is the average of the entries of $x$.

Comment: Is $a$ also an arbitrary vector?

Comment: And what does $(a - \bar x)^2$ mean?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, a is also an arbitrary vector. In $(a-\bar{x})^2$ the $ \bar{x}$ denotes a scalar whose value is the average of x. The textbook is Matrix Algebra - James E. Gentle and this equation is on the pp. 70.

Comment: Is $a$ a scalar here?  Note that $x_c$ is perpendicular to any vector that has constant entries.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes you are right. a is a scalar. However I cannot construct an inner product form of $x_c$ and $a$ from the equation.

Comment: Hmmm... I think we're still missing something... is $A$ a stochastic matrix?  That is, do all of its rows add up to $1$?

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I am going to do this now.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No. It says "Furthermore, for any scalar a, n-vector x, and n × n matrix A, we have" that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
(x-a)^TA(x-a) = \\
(x_c + (\bar x - a))^TA(x_c + (\bar x - a)) =\\
x_c^TAx_c +
(x_c)^TA(\bar x - a) + 
(\bar x - a)^TA x_c + 
(\bar x - a)^TA(\bar x - a) = \\
\operatorname{trace}(Ax_c x_c^T) +
(x_c)^TA(\bar x - a) + 
(\bar x - a)^TA x_c + 
(\bar x - a)^TA(\bar x - a) =
$$
I believe that any further manipulation requires some nice property of $x_c,\bar x$ relative to $A$.

---

Noting that $A$ is symmetric, we have
$$
(x_c)^TA(\bar x - a) = [(x_c)^TA(\bar x - a)]^T = (\bar x - a)^TAx_c
$$
So far, we have
$$
(x-a)^TA(x-a) =\\
\operatorname{trace}(Ax_c x_c^T) +
2(\bar x - a)^TA x_c + 
(\bar x - a)^TA(\bar x - a)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I stuck at the same place. I don't know how can I extract the tr(A) from the terms of the form $tr(x^TAy)$.

Comment: I don't think it's generally possible; I think there's something specific about these vectors that needs to be used.

Comment: note that
$$
(\bar x - a)^TA(\bar x - a) = 
(\bar x - a)^2 1^TA1 = 
(\bar x - a)^2 \sum_{ij} A_{ij}
$$

Comment: With n = 2, a = $(3, 3)^T$, x = $(1.5, 5.8)^T$ and A = $\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 2 &8 \end{bmatrix}$, I find the equation is wrong. Maybe the author forgot some prerequisites. Thank you!

Comment: My guess: symmetric with row sums = $1$.  You're welcome.